# unable to store the filename as Sheet name from while importing

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to import multiple files Sheet 1 data and store the data in current workbook with different sheetnames as file names.
 Currently it can import,Selecting Sheet1 data,Copying it and pasting it in current workbook but not with file name. can anybody help me on this matter?

Also I want to know that if this is the best way in case of memory usage as my Objective is to import with large excel files.Please guide me

My Code pasted here..

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FileList As Variant
    Dim impSheet As String
    Dim ActWorkBk As String
    Dim ImpWorkBk As String
    Dim NoImport As Boolean


    impSheet = "Sheet1"
    FileList = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook", MultiSelect:=True)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    NoImport = False

    For i = 1 To UBound(FileList)
        Workbooks.Open (FileList(i))
        ImpWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(impSheet).Select
        If Err > 0 Then
            NoImport = True
            GoTo nxt
        End If
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(impSheet).Copy after:=Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Sheets(Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Sheets.Count)

       'Renames the imported sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = FileList(i) & " - " & impSheet
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0

nxt:
        Workbooks(ImpWorkBk).Activate
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Activate
    Next i

    'Error if some sheets were not found
    If NoImport = True Then MsgBox "One or more sheets could not be found and imported!"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @A.S.H you have given the Answer

ActiveSheet.Name = Mid(Replace(FileList(i), "\", "_"), 4) & " - " & impSheet

but it is not working...
like if i select date1.xlsx & date2.xlsx ....Sheet name will be date1.xlsx-Sheet1,date2.xlsx-Sheet1....

Comment: I've already removed that answer, quickly because I felt it was incomplete. It also did not address your more important question *"I want to know that if this is the best way"* ... But anyway, from your code it seemed that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes..that I want....Also FileList is a variant datatype and it is holding the file location address..am i right?? if so is there any way to extract only filename??

Comment: *"but not with file name"* can you reword this? But not *what* with file name? I don't understand what that means

Comment: @Subhasish1315 of course you can, I will write an answer for that.

Comment: Like If Import date1.xlsx the newly created sheetname will be date1.xlsx-Sheet1.....the Current code is renaming the sheet as Sheet1

Comment: @Subhasish1315 Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As I finally understood, you want the sheet's name to include only the file's name without the path.

```
Dim newSheetName As String, ch
' First get the file's name without path
newSheetName = Mid(FileList(i), 1 + InStrRev(FileList(1), "\"), 1000) & " - " & impsheet

' Trucate the name to the last 31 characters
newSheetName = Right(newSheetName, 31)

' Now remove any forbidden characters from sheet's name
For Each ch In Array("\", "/", "*", "?", ":", "[" , "]")
    newSheetName = Replace(newSheetName, ch, "_")
Next
```

As to the question about "is this the best way", it seems that your overall code can be improved. Basically you can group those changes to `Application.DisplayAlerts=..` stuff to outside the loop.

**Most importantly,** you should get rid of the `.Activate`, `.ActiveThing` stuff and work with explicit object references.

Answer (score 0):

To strip out special characters from the string (that can't be used in an excel sheet name) use this function:

```
Public Function Var_Clean(ByVal strInput As String)
    If InStr(1, strInput, "\") > 0 Then strInput = Replace(strInput, "\", "_")
    If InStr(1, strInput, "/") > 0 Then strInput = Replace(strInput, "/", "_")
    If InStr(1, strInput, "?") > 0 Then strInput = Replace(strInput, "?", "_")
    If InStr(1, strInput, "*") > 0 Then strInput = Replace(strInput, "*", "_")
    If InStr(1, strInput, "[") > 0 Then strInput = Replace(strInput, "[", "_")
    If InStr(1, strInput, "]") > 0 Then strInput = Replace(strInput, "]", "_")
    If InStr(1, strInput, ":") > 0 Then strInput = Replace(strInput, ":", "_")
Var_Clean = strInput
End Function
```

and ensure the length of the name does not exceed 31 characters

```
if len(x) > 31 then x = left(x,31)
```

Comment: `x = left(x,31)` does the job without the need of `if`. If it has less than 31 characters, then it won't be affected :)

Comment: You can also do the `Replace` stuff without checking. Better yet, group them in a loop; i.e. `For each ch in array("\", "/", "*", "?", ":", "[", "]") strInput = Replace(strInput, ch, "_")`

Comment: You actually don't need any of those `If`. The `Replace` method would also work without it, and personally I would use a Regular Expression instead of all of those `Replace`

Comment: @VictorMoraes Happy to learn better ways of working, if you have a better solution (sounds like it!) then please answer and I can always delete this one.

Comment: @Zerk I actually came here by accident and didn't quite understand OP's issue. Not sure if this will solve the issue

Answer (score -2):

does your sheet name compile with the sheet naming conventions.
you can find them in the link below[Excel Naming Conventions](http://www.excelcodex.com/2012/06/worksheets-naming-conventions/)

try switching your hyphen(-) for an underscore(_)

Comment: A question/comment ought not to be posted as an answer. Either provide the methods to achieve the objective or post as a comment.

Comment: I have given him the resources he needs to correct the error. Its not a comment its an answer.

Comment: @SivaprasathV How it is an answer? It do not solve the question.

Comment: i gave him the resource along with a solution to change his hypen in the name to avoid errors due to naming conventions.

Comment: @SivaprasathV If someone is starving and does not know how to cook, giving them a raw chicken and saying "cook this" is not a solution.

Comment: what about the part about the switching hyphen with underscore. thats the answer the documentation is to justify the change